# Passing in parameters to dynamically created components React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```jsx
let itemName;
for (let j=0; j< Object.keys(menu[location][mealTime][sectionName]).length; j++) {
  itemName = Object.keys(menu[diningHall][mealTime][sectionName])[j];
                    
  if (processAllergyArr(menu[diningHall][mealTime][sectionName][itemName]['itemAllergyArr'], exclusionArr, inclusionArr)) {
    if (itemName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLocaleLowerCase()) != -1) {
      console.log(itemName)
      arrOfItems.push(
        <View key={j} style={{borderWidth: 1, height: 40}}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={j}
            onPress={() => {onItemClick(itemName)}}
            style={{height: '100%', display: 'flex', flexDirection:'row'}}
          >
```

Here I have a variable called itemName that I try to pass in as a parameter in a function called onPress of my touchable opacity component. My touchable opacity component is in an array of components of its kind which are then included in the return function of my component.

The problem here is that the onPress function passes in the same exact parameter into onItemClick regardless of which item is associated with the opacity button.

The console.log(itemName) will log different item names but the function in onPress will use the same exact one

I was thinking that bind may be useful in this scenario but wasn't sure of how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you declared `itemName` outside of for loop.

Since you are trying to make a component, it shouldn't be used like pushing values into an array.

UI Rendering will be happen in your page and this will result in `itemName` being the last value of its signed value.

A way to solve this is to put itemName inside of your For-Loop

```
for (let j=0; j< Object.keys(menu[location][mealTime][sectionName]).length; j++) {
  const itemName = Object.keys(menu[diningHall][mealTime][sectionName])[j];
                    
  if (processAllergyArr(menu[diningHall][mealTime][sectionName][itemName]['itemAllergyArr'], exclusionArr, inclusionArr)) {
    if (itemName.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLocaleLowerCase()) != -1) {
      console.log(itemName)
      arrOfItems.push(
        <View key={j} style={{borderWidth: 1, height: 40}}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={j}
            onPress={() => {onItemClick(itemName)}}
            style={{height: '100%', display: 'flex', flexDirection:'row'}}
          >
```

Declaring inside for loop should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you this worked! Could you explain in further depth why it uses the last signed value of itemName?

Comment: I'll try to explain as far as I know. Making a component and assigning to Dom and Render Tree, finally showing in layout is not activity that is synchronized with rest of your code. So for-loop loops faster than rendering, and results in itemName reassigning before Component is rendered with its value. Better practice would be using map function inside render(or return in functional component) or just use flatlist to make a listed views.